# Node C++ Addon for Electron/Cordova using Quasar

Tags: c++, node.js

Need a Quasar, Electron, Cordova, Nodejs, expert.

FULL TASK:

- Help me include the compiled c++ node add-on that I created on an Electron app (using electron-rebuild to match the version), on my QUASAR project.
- Same for Cordova, on Quasar.

DETAILS:
Please help. I am desperate.
I am a developer trying to finish a job and I can't find the answer to the problem.

I was able to succesfully develop a Node C++ Addon that works on Nodejs. I was able to compile it with node-gyp and got a myModule.node binary file. I tested this file on a Nodejs environment, it works fine.

However, I cannot import it on Electron/Cordova using Quasar. I tried adding on Electron electron-main.js:

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <napi.h>
#include <electron/electron_version.h>

#if defined(ELECTRON_VERSION_MAJOR) && ELECTRON_VERSION_MAJOR >= 9
  #include <electron/native_mate/constructor.h>
#else
  #include <electron/common/native_mate_converters/gurl_converter.h>
#endif

Napi::Boolean IsDevToolsOpen(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();

  // Get the current BrowserWindow using the electron module
  Napi::Object electron = env.Require("electron");
  Napi::Value browser_window = electron.Get("BrowserWindow");
  Napi::Object current_window = browser_window.Call("getFocusedWindow");
  if (current_window.IsNull()) {
    current_window = browser_window.Call("getAllWindows").As<Napi::Array>().Get(0);
  }

  // Check if any DevTools extensions are installed
  Napi::Object devtools = current_window.Get("webContents").Get("devToolsWebContents");
  Napi::Object extensions = devtools.Call("getDevToolsExtensions");
  Napi::Array keys = extensions.GetPropertyNames();
  bool devtools_open = (keys.Length() > 0);

  return Napi::Boolean::New(env, devtools_open);
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  exports.Set("IsDevToolsOpen", Napi::Function::New(env, IsDevToolsOpen));
  return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)
```

This example assumes that you're using Electron 9 or later, which uses the native-mate library for interfacing with Electron APIs. If you're using an earlier version of Electron, you'll need to use the GURLConverter class instead.

Once you've built and loaded this module in your Electron app, you can call the IsDevToolsOpen() function to check if DevTools is open:

```
const myAddon = require('./my-addon.node');
const devtoolsOpen = myAddon.IsDevToolsOpen();
if (devtoolsOpen) {
  // Provide secrets to DevTools
} else {
  // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Did you see the same thing?